# Neo4j, bulk load with Cypher commands

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and there must be something I don't understand about the basics.

I've many objects in Java and I want to use them to populate a Neo4j graph, using the Java driver and Cypher. My code works like this:

```
// nodes
for ( Person person: persons )
  session.run ( String.format ( 
    "CREATE ( :Person { id: '%s', name: \"%s\", surname: \"%s\" })",
    person.getId(), person.getName(), person.getSurname ()
  ));

// relations
session.run ( "CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id)" );

for ( Friendship friendship: friendships )
  session.run ( String.format ( 
    "MATCH ( from:Person { id: '%s' } ), ( to:Person { id: '%s' } )\n" +
    "CREATE (from)-:KNOWS->(to)\n",
    friendship.getFrom().getId(), 
    friendship.getTo().getId() 
  ));
```

(indeed, it's slightly more complicated, cause I have a dozen node types and about the same number of relation types).

Now, this is very slow, like more than 1 hour to load 300k nodes and 1M relations (on a fairly fast MacBookPro, with Neo4j taking 12/16GB of RAM).

Am I doing it the wrong way? Should I use the [batch inserter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert-examples.html) instead? (I would prefer to be able to access the graphDB via network). Would I gain something by grouping more insertions into one transaction? (From the documentation, It seems transactions are only useful for rolling back and for isolation needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming from Neo4j in Python, but I think the issue here is with your Cypher commands. I have two suggestions.

It may be faster to Match edges separately. On my primitive benchmark I see a difference of 24ms vs 15ms with this (EDIT: This benchmark is dubious):

```
MATCH ( from:Person { id: '%s' } )
MATCH ( to:Person { id: '%s' } )
CREATE (from)-:KNOWS->(to)
```

Another option is to use UNWIND. I use this with the BOLT interface to send fewer transactions but without using the Batch Inserter. Forgive the Python implementation I'm copying here, and hopefully you can look at this along with the Javascript Neo4j Driver docs to convert it.

```
payload = {"list":[{"a":"Name1","b":"Name2"},{"a":"Name3","b":"Name4"}]}

statement = "UNWIND {list} AS d "
statement += "MATCH (A:Person {name: d.a}) "
statement += "MATCH (B:Person {name: d.b}) " 
statement += "MERGE (A)-[:KNOWS]-(B) "

tx = session.begin_transaction()
tx.run(statement,payload)
tx.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it would work in my case. 24-15ms aren't a lot different, considering my application is populating its internal graph (using hash maps) in less than 3mins, while Neo4j takes ages to do the same. That cannot be right, it should take more or less the same. 

As for WIND, I think sending a list as a parameter would eventually turn into a too big query, considering that I have so many nodes and edges.

Comment: My benchmark there may be off, but I strongly suggest at least trying UNWIND.  Your payload list doesn't have to be *all* your data, you could chunk it out (as I do in practice, not in above example code).  If payload is of size ~100k and you can fill your edges with N transactions, that's going to save tons of time relative to N*100k individual transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth to report my experience on this.

I've followed the @sjc suggestion and tried with UNWIND. However, that wasn't so simple, because Cypher doesn't allow you to parameterise node labels or relation types (and I have a dozen labels and relation types). But eventually, I was able to loop over all possible types and send enough items (about 1000) to each UNWIND chunk.

The code using UNWIND is much faster, yet not fast enough, in my opinion (should be OK on a decent PC and with few million nodes, not very good with hundreds of millions of nodes, or more).

The inserter component is much faster (few seconds to upload 1-2 million nodes), although it requires to bring the HTTP access down and I've had a lot of problems with its dependency on Lucene 5.4, because I need to use it inside an application (which produces data) that uses Lucene 6, and awful things happened when I tried to simply swap 5.4 with 6 in the classpath. I've read that [there is some mechanism to make this possible](https://github.com/apatry/neo4j-lucene4-index), but it doesn't seem easy and certainly isn't so well documented.

I definitely didn't expect all such troubles for executing such a basic operation efficiently.

Comment: Cypher doesn't allow parameterized labels or relation types, but the statement is built of strings, so you can loop over lists of your node types to simply recreate the string for each type.

Comment: Hi @sjc. This is an old question, much happened since the. I had to split my data on a per-label basis and then the node type is sent as a constant part of the Cypher query that works with many nodes of the same type. if I get you correctly, this is similar to what you suggest.

A project where I've implemented such approach is here:
https://github.com/Rothamsted/rdf2neo